# Converting unicode values

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, type-conversion

I'm testing Unicode support in an application.  I have a database, one record per unicode character.  Each row stores the code point, decimal value and the actual unicode character.  I need to create a method to compare the actual character to either the code point or the decimal value so I know it's coming across correctly.

I get all values as unicode strings from the database (ex:  decimal value is u'65593' and Code Point can be something like u'10039' or u'\u10039' or u'0x10039' what ever format we need).  I've tried many different methods and found that python 2.7.x works fine with unichar() and ord() with values below 65535.  Any value over return either an exception trying to convert to a unicode character or the wrong decimal value.  The actual character is being returned back in UTF-8.

Is there another way to compare the results?  I either have to up convert the decimal or down convert the character for comparison.

I have also tried converting to binary and then to int and the values returned are wrong at the same location (65535).

```
value = int( ''.join(format(ord(cur),'0>8b') for cur in char), 2)   #unichr(dec)
```

Comment: Have you tried using a UCS-4 build instead?

Comment: HAHA what is UCS-4?  I'm using whats built into Mac OS 10.11.4.

Comment: >>> print sys.maxunicode
65535

Comment: That confirms that you have a UCS-2 build.

Comment: Is there a way to rebuild what is provided by Apple?  Not sure but I think those folders are locked down.

Comment: Dunno. You can build your own copy though.

Comment: After thinking about this I'm not sure I can test in that environment and require our users to move.  They also would have to compile there own versions.  Is there another way to accomplish this?  Most our users will simply do comparisons stringa == stringb type tests which will work as the strings are in UTF-8.  I just need a method to up convert or down convert. That will allow ME to verify that the correct code point was downloaded.  IOW I could up convert the decimal 'string' to UTF-8 and compare it with the character downloaded.

Comment: For codepoints >65535 you need to use a slightly different form of Unicode escape code that uses an upper-case U, eg `s=u'\U00010039';print s,s.encode('utf8')`. FWIW, the standard [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html) module can be used to lookup a codepoint by name and vice versa. You may also find [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) helpful. Ned Batchelder is a SO veteran.

Comment: WOW!! That is amazing.  I tried about 5 different formats and that wasn't one of them.  A little testing shows that you need to pad out value to include 8 hex values after the \U.  So this format \Uxxxxxxxx where x is a Hex digit from 0 to F.  Thanks PM 2Ring for a SIMPLE solution.

Comment: OK got the final answer for me.  From my database I'm getting a string like u'\\U00001234'.  These are escaped to protect the string.  I need to use codepoint.decode('unicode-escape') to up convert the value to a unicode character.  This is terrific thanks for the help!!  @PM2Ring

Comment: I tried just having the alpha numeric portion in the Database.  IOW:  without the \U and locally add that in my python and that didn't work.  I got errors stating that the value was being truncated.

Comment: No worries. I'm glad you got it working.